# How is it possible to overwrite dataframe in a list with a for loop in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello I want to modify my dataframes in a list with a for loop. My function works well and my dataframes are modified inside the function but once I want to have these new dataframes (with the same name as the old ones), it is not the dataframes that are shown but the old ones. I conclude that I can't overwrite my old dataframes.

All my dataframes in the list are of the form :

```
index  customer_region  number_order    distance_between_seller_customer    date_last_order mean_days_between_orders    mean_item_per_order mean_volume_item_ordered    
69  Southeast   1.0 1.850759    736411.0    0.0 
74  Southeast   1.0 0.250155    736404.0    0.0 
93  Northeast   1.0 20.223906   736416.0    0.0 
101 Southeast   1.0 0.989547    736366.0    0.0
```

Preparation

```
all_dfs = [sample_1strim, sample_2strim, sample_3strim]
```

function to normalized digital columns, encoded nominal column to digital columns and modify old dataframe per dataframe merge of previous modification :

```
def get_df_name(df):    #to get dataframe name
    name =[x for x in globals() if globals()[x] is df][0]
    return name

def standartization_encodage (frame):
  X = frame.copy()
  categorical_columns = X.select_dtypes(['category','object']).columns
  numerical_columns = X.select_dtypes(['int64','float64']).columns
  X[numerical_columns] = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X[numerical_columns])
  one_hot_encoded = pd.get_dummies(X[categorical_columns])
  X = pd.merge(X[numerical_columns], one_hot_encoded,left_index = True, right_index = True)
  X.shape
  X = X.set_index(frame.index)

  return X

            
for i, df in enumerate(all_dfs):
    all_dfs[i] = standartization_encodage(df)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is, I think, a fairly simple question hidden behind lots of irrelevant code. Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: As you asked me, I have minimized my code to the essentials and put what my dataframes look like. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a function and apply it to all elements in the list of dataframes.

```
def transform_df(df):
    # your code in the loop
    return transformed_df

all_dfs = [transform_df(df) for df in all_dfs]
```

Comment: I tried to use your method but unfortunately, arriving at the second dataframe, the transform_df function is no longer recognized and the first dataframe that is passed into the function has not been modified outside the function.

Comment: Thank you for your proposal, I was inspired by it to modify my code but unfortunately, the old files are not overwritten by the new modified dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I *think* you have misunderstood how variables and lists work in Python. You have

```
df1 = (some dataframe)
all_dfs = [df1]
```

This means that you have a dataframe, and that the variable `df1`, as well as the first list entry, hold references to that dataframe:

```
df1 -------> (ORIGINAL DATAFRAME)
               ^
               |
all_dfs ---> [ 0 ]
```

Then, you effectively do

```
df1_1 = all_dfs[0].copy()
df1_1 = (stuff that modifies df1_1)
all_dfs[0] = df1_1
```

This means that you have created a new dataframe, and changed the first entry of the list to refer to this new dataframe. However, the variable `df1` still refers to the original dataframe!

```
df1 -------> (ORIGINAL DATAFRAME)

all_dfs ---> [ 0 ]
               |
               v
              (NEW DATAFRAME)
```

You cannot change a variable indirectly through a list as (I think) you are trying to do. You might be able to get the same effect if, instead of creating a new df, you can modify the existing one in place (unfortunately, I am not familiar enough with pandas to know off hand whether that is possible).

Comment: thank you for your explanations. I modified the content of my loop according to it but I have to launch it manually on each of my dataframes of all_dfs because in spite of my numerous researches and tests I do not manage to replace my old dataframes by those modified.